# Ensure vendor bundles are cached by retaining previous hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, webpack

I'm trying to use [splitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin) to separate vendor deps and my scripts into separate bundles and it seems to be working using [the example they provide](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-2). However I don't think the caching aspect is working as webpacking the project will generate `app-087620f3a62a222ec83e.js` and `vendors-087620f3a62a222ec83e.js` files, but on making a change only to my code generates new hashes for both files, where I would expect the vendor's hash suffix to remain the same. The output object within my webpack config is:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
  publicPath: '/',
 filename: 'scripts/[name]-[hash].js'
},
```

I have tried changing `[hash]` to `[chunkhash]` thinking that sounded a little more reasonable based on the doc's [guide to caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames), but webpack fails with the error:

> `ERROR in chunk bundleUnAuth [entry] scripts/[chunkhash].js Cannot use [chunkhash] or [contenthash] for chunk in 'scripts/[chunkhash].js' (use [hash] instead)`

The replacement for the `commonsChunkPlugin` doesn't indicate it requires something like `NamedModulesPlugin` or `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` as [its predecessor indicates it does](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk) for nuanced situations in which this same thing could occur.

#### How can I ensure the chunking plugin retains the same hash for an unchanged vendor file, while updating the hash for scripts I control that have changed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [runtimechunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimization-runtimechunk) field together with splitChunksPlugin.

For example:

```
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'manifest',
  },
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
  },
```

by configuring the `runtimeChunk`, a new chunk called `manifest` will be created. This trunk contains webpack runtime and `manifest`. The `manifest` is the part that changes everytime you change your code. By extracting it to a separate chunk, the hash of your vendors trunk would remain the same between builds.

For production build, `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` or `NamedModulesPlugin` is also recommended. Since they can keep the module ids of your vendor modules remain the same when you rename/move your application codes.

Comment: I in fact did try using that option but only got through the `true` option before my eyes started getting heavy. Where are the docs that indicate `manifest` is an option? I’m missing that in the link.

Comment: the string `manifest` does not have any special meaning. you can change it to whatever you like. I use `manifest` just for convention. the related code is [at here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js#L240-L251) and it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I see. It is just a string not contained in the entry, like from commonsChunkPlugin. Gotcha. One more question, do you know what is meant by `This might result in a large chunk containing all external packages. It is recommended to only include your core frameworks and utilities and dynamically load the rest of the dependencies.` from the doc you linked.

Comment: For example, in your application, you use qrcode.react to render a qrcode in a dialog. by setting test rule to `/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/`, all modules under `node_modules` are bundle to manifest chunk. Which means even user do not open the dialog, the qrcode.react is loaded everytime user views your page. To optimize this, we can only include the core frameworks(like react react-dom react-router etc.) in `manifest` and load the qrcode.react module on demand.  Check [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

Comment: Surely it doesn't load everything in `node_modules` just modules that are `import`ed or `require`d somewhere in tree of entry-point imports.

Comment: yes, that's also what I mean here. hope that helps you a little bit